# PaypalPlus iFrame integration with Payment Logos

Tags: magento, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

How can I add the payment logo to the PaypalPlus iFrame integration? We have 2 extensions for PaypalPlus, the old one shows payment logos for Paypal, direct debit etc. but the new one not.  (The Image has class class="paymentMethodIcon")

In all SDK & Integration guides I did not find any information about this. 
Who can help? Is this something which depends on integration and is controlled by Paypal or is there any setting?

[Thats how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAEee.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Sorry, did you read this? This is a Paypal Rest API related thing, I think there is a parameter that Paypal shows the Payment Logos.

Comment: Just because you can program against an API and that your question mentions an API it doesn't mean that your question is about programming. You need to show the code that is not working for you and where you are stuck. Otherwise this sounds like you're asking for a setting config (which isn't programming).

Answer (score 0):

The payment wall iframe is configured by paypal with a whitelist of allowed domains (see [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)).

- The image URL must be https (specified in the [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-plus/germany/how-to/integrate-third-party-payments/?mark=imageUrl))
- Your images must be on a server on the whitelist.
- This includes: The image URL can not have a custom port.
- PayPal automatically adds the domain containing the PPP script to the whitelist.

If you look into the browser console you might be able to see an error like this:
`Refused to load the image 'https://my-domain.de:7443/images/payment_sofort_small.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src https://*.paypalobjects.com https://ak1s.abmr.net https://ak1.abmr.net https://ak1s.mathtag.com https://akamai.mathtag.com https://my-domain.de".`

This is how it looked in my case:
[image]